# Update using join or nasted sub-query Hibernate (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a problem creating HQL that updates entity CommitteeMembership with nested queries or using joins, i tried this query first:

```
update CommitteeMemberShip cms set cms.isDeleted=1 
where cms.committeeCycle.committee.id=:committeeId
```

but the generated SQL was wrong as following:

```
update CommitteeMemberShip cross join  set isDeleted=1 where committee_id=?
```

without any this after "cross join" makes Hibernate throws SQLGrammarException

After that, i have changed my query to use sub-query:

```
update CommitteeMemberShip cms set cms.isDeleted=1 
where cms.id in (select cmsIn.id from CommitteeMemberShip cmsIn inner join 
cmsIn.committeeCycle cc inner join cc.committee c where c.id=:committeeId)
```

now Hibernate throws

```
java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'CommitteeMemberShip' for 
update in FROM clause
```

any one have any idea how i can write this update query in HQL??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

update CommitteeMemberShip cms set cms.isDeleted=1 
where cms.id = some(select cmsIn.id from CommitteeMemberShip cmsIn inner join 
cmsIn.committeeCycle cc inner join cc.committee c where c.id=:committeeId)

Comment: I think this will do exactly what the second try of sub-query in question, it throws:
    java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table     'CommitteeMemberShip' for update in FROM clause

Comment: I am not sure but try this 
update CommitteeMemberShip cms join CommitteeMemberShip cms2 on cms.id=cms2.id set cms.isDeleted=1 
where cms2.committeeCycle.committee.id=:committeeId

Comment: You cannot write join after the entity name or alias, it throws org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found 'join'

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
"UPDATE table1 r SET r.column = @value WHERE r.column IN("SELECT rd.Id FROM r.table2 rd WHERE rd.Column='"+@value+"' AND rd.Column='"+value+"'";

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HQL does not yet support path expressions / implicit joins in DML statements. [Here's how jOOQ does it](https://blog.jooq.org/jooq-3-17-supports-implicit-join-also-in-dml/) (in SQL, assuming all paths are to-one relationships (Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ)):

```sql
UPDATE CommitteeMemberShip cms
SET cms.isDeleted = 1
WHERE (
  SELECT Committee.id
  FROM Committee
  WHERE (
    SELECT CommitteeCycle.committeeId
    FROM CommitteeCycle
    WHERE CommitteeCycle.id = cms.committeeCycleId
  ) = Committee.id 
) = :committeeId
```

Your own approach didn't work because you repeated the `CommitteeMemberShip` entity unnecessarily. That's a known MySQL limitation, see:
[MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

This would have worked, I suspect?

```sql
UPDATE CommitteeMemberShip cms
SET cms.isDeleted = 1
WHERE cms.committeeCycleId IN (
  SELECT CommitteeCycle.id
  FROM CommitteeCycle cc
  JOIN cc.committee c
  WHERE c.id = :committeeId
)
```

Starting with Hibernate 6 and their support for derived tables, you might be able to work around MySQL's limitation like this ([the same way as jOOQ does it out of the box, see here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6583)):

```sql
UPDATE CommitteeMemberShip cms 
SET cms.isDeleted=1 
WHERE cms.id IN (
  -- Wrap the query once more in a derived table
  SELECT t.id
  FROM (
    SELECT cmsIn.id 
    FROM CommitteeMemberShip cmsIn 
    JOIN cmsIn.committeeCycle cc 
    JOIN cc.committee c WHERE c.id=:committeeId
  ) t
)
```